# Access custom controller-defined enum in custom component?

Tags: visualforce

Given a custom VF component that uses a custom controller; the controller defines an enum:

```
global with sharing class My_Controller {
  public Case currCase {get; set; }
  public enum StatusValue {RED, YELLOW, GREEN}

  public StatusValues getColorStatus() {
    return StatusValue.RED;  //demo code - just return red
  }
}
```

In the component, I want to test using the enum value:

```
<apex:image url='stopsign.png' rendered="{!colorStatus == StatusValue.RED}" />
```

But trying to save (via Force.com IDE) responds, `Save Error: Unknown property 'My_Controller.statusValue'`

StatusValue is a public enum, it should be visible here.  How do I reference this enum from the component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess, but do you need to quantify where StatusValue is by prefixing it with the class name and possibly a namespace prefix?

E.g.

```
<apex:image url='stopsign.png' rendered="{!colorStatus == My_Controller.StatusValue.RED}" />
```

---

On second thought it probably isn't a namespace issue. I did find [Having trouble referencing a user defined enum](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Having-trouble-referencing-a-user-defined-enum/td-p/153363) which suggests making a string property for the name.

From the link (with modifications to bring it inline with the question):

> I don't think you can directly reference the enum since the enum
>   itself is not visible to the page and you can't make it a property.  I
>   resolved the issue by adding in one more controller property.

```
public String currentStatusValue { get{ return getColorStatus().name(); }}
```

> Then change your page to be:

```
<apex:image url='stopsign.png' rendered="{!currentStatusValue == 'RED'}" />
```

---

Personally, I'd look at making a property that returns a boolean directly. E.g.

```
public boolean renderStopSign { get{ return getColorStatus() == StatusValue.RED; }}

<apex:image url='stopsign.png' rendered="{!renderStopSign }" />
```

The practicality of this approach will depend on how many values you want to test for.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  Truthfully, I assumed (I know!) that it wouldn't work since the error message already refers to 'My_Controller.statusValue'.  I have now tried it explicitly as suggested, but I get the same error.

Comment: Daniel:  I'm worried you may be right, but if I'm going to pass strings around, there's no point in having an enum - the values are only used to return statuses to the component.

Comment: @JasonClark I agree, enum support seems a bit weak in Visualforce if you have to fall back to strings as a workaround.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I believe it is correct; there is at present no way for a component to see an enum defined by its controller.

Comment: seems like it would have been very easy for the devs to expose the enum.name field in VF.  Oh well, another half baked Salesforce feature

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, as Daniel suggests I don't think it's a namespace issue - I think maybe Visualforce just doesn't know what to do with the enum datatype.

So:

```
public String getColorStatus() {
    return StatusValue.RED.name();  //demo code - just return red
  }
```

And:

```
<apex:image url='stopsign.png' rendered="{!colorStatus == 'RED'}" />
```

Would work.

Comment: hmmm, in some cases that might defeat using the enum itself